# Use exact QueryRenderer in different component

Tags: reactjs, relay

I am a beginner in Relay & React. If I write this exact QueryRenderer in multiple component, will the network call multiple times? Or it will only call once? I check in Network tab (Chrome Debugger) and I saw only 1 though. If it will trigger multiple network call, what is the best way to consolidate?
https://relay.dev/docs/en/query-renderer

```
    <QueryRenderer
      environment={environment}
      query={graphql`
        query ExampleQuery($pageID: ID!) {
          page(id: $pageID) {
            name
          }
        }
      `}
      variables={{
        pageID: '110798995619330',
      }}
      render={renderQuery}
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Relay `environment`, the `query` results will be cached.

Therefore for same query `variables` no additional network calls will occur.

In addition you should use [Relay Hooks](https://relay.dev/docs/en/experimental/api-reference) (like used in FB) which provide support for Concurrent Mode (the main reason to actually use Relay).

> Note that this question is a symptom of [Premature Optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)